# Serving static files with node express

Tags: html, node.js, apache, express

#### Background

I'm serving a webapp on https://jienan.xyz/m, in Apache I redirect the link to localhost:3001/memo with

```
ProxyPass /m http://localhost:3001/memo
ProxyPassReverse /m http://localhost:3001/memo
```

I'm listening to port 3001, with express. If no params or queries attached, `./html/web_portal.html` will be returned. I placed app logo, favicon and other imgs  that I hoped to served statically under `./html/icon/` with express.static:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html/'));
```

In the web portal html, I refer the links of img with `<img ... src="/icon/ic_pullsh.png"/>`

#### Problem

After all these implementations, the imgs can't be loaded when accessed from [domain](https://jienan.xyz/m). I can see the img has the link `https://jienan.xyz/icon/ic_pullsh.png`.

If I use the ip address http://130.211.211.220:3001/memo, the img can be seen, with the address of `http://130.211.211.220:3001/icon/ic_pullsh.png`.

#### Question

How can I change the implementations to serve the files statically, to make it visible from domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is not a very smart answer in my mind.

Since I redirect `jienan.xyz/m` to `localhost:3001/memo`, the correct format of link to static file should be `https://jienan.xyz/m/icon/ic_pullsh.png`, and it will be redirected to `http://130.211.211.220:3001/memo/icon/ic_pullsh.png`.

What happens is it will look in the `./html/memo/icon/` folder for that png. So I have to declare to serve static file under `/html/` in express, and put all the files under `/html/memo/`.

Maybe it's not a good idea to redirect request to /memo at first